# How to match a "something":"thestring" pattern?

Tags: javascript, regex

<sup>*Note: I changed the title of the question, as well as all reference to JSON so that the question better reflects my problem. I got several times the advice of "better iterate the object than work on a serialized version" but I believe (and am certainly mistaken and wrong) that searching for a well-defined pattern in a string is easier than go for iterative or recursive code to iterate an object*</sup>

I need to extract the pattern `"something":"thestring"` from a string.

The source string will have many other combinations such as `"something":[{"thestring":{"key":18,"anotherkey":"astring"}}]`, from which only the pair `"anotherkey":"astring"` is sought for.

I am specifically interested in getting the content of the value, that is `thestring` in the first example (and `astring` in the second one).

I tried to match `".*?","(.*?)"` but I get more than just the pair, matching the comma after the quote (and it goes downhill form there).

An example of a test string and my failed test is on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uxS9k0/1)

Comment: The values you want to match are always between quotes, and preceded by a key which is also between quotes ?

Comment: Why just not make a temporary object, and find the strings?

Comment: (("[_a-zA-Z0-9]+"):("[_a-zA-Z0-9]+"))

Comment: @Gawil: yes, this is the structure

Comment: @Teemu: I have the source object. I wanted to flatten it to search for the strings (I am not interested in the place they are in, just the fact that they are strings), instead of walking the object which may be quite complex.

Comment: Iterating the object shouldn't be that complex, there are plenty of examples at SO. Also you can find examples of flattening of an object structure without stringifying it.

Comment: You are just making life more difficult for yourself. Just access the object.

Comment: @Andy: well, I believe that a single line of regex would be simpler than iterating though a complex, several layers deep object with nested arrays and dicts. YMMV

Comment: I am a fan of regex and I still think this is a terrible idea. Why not just walk the object?

Comment: @NullUserException: because the object is complex and the iterative or recursive code to go deep (and take into account the variety of elements found (dict, array, string, number) make me think that working on a plain string where what I want to find is very well defined would be easier. Why do you think think this is a terrible idea (so that I do not take a bad road if there is really an issue ahead)?

Comment: @WoJ In other words, you've an object, and you want to extract only the values of the object properties which are strings, and strings within arrays should be ignored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I would write this:

```
function extractStrings(obj) {
    var stringSet = [];
    function extractStringsHelper(obj) {
        if (typeof obj === 'string' && stringSet.indexOf(obj) === -1) {
            stringSet.push(obj);
        } else if (typeof obj === 'array') {
            for (var i=0; i<obj.length; i++) {
                extractStringsHelper(obj);
            }
        } else if (typeof obj === 'object' && obj !== null) {
            for (var key in obj) {
                if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    extractStringsHelper(obj[key]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    extractStringsHelper(obj);
    return stringSet;
}

> extractStrings({'a': "strA", 'b': ["strB1", 1, "strB2", {'n': "strC"}]})
> (4) ["strA", "strB1", "strB2", "strC"]
```

You can also go the regex route and look for:

```
"[^"]+":"([^"]+)"
```

Here is your example with the modified regex: https://regex101.com/r/uxS9k0/2

But this path is dark and full of terrors. For example, it breaks if the string contains an escaped double quote. Once you start accounting for all the possible cases, you are basically rewriting a JSON tokenizer.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this regex :**
If you really want to work on a string, this regex will do what you want, as long as what you look for is always between quotes and preceded by a key between quotes :
`"\w+":"(\w+)"`
Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/yj0dWp/1)
The value will be captured in group 1

---

**Here is how to get your value :**

```js
var regex = /"\w+":"(\w+)"/g;
var json = "\"something\":\"thestring\"\n\"something\":[{\n\t\"thestring\":{\n\t\t\"key\":18,\n\t\t\"anotherkey\":\"astring\"\n\t}\n}]";
console.log(json);

var match = regex.exec(json);
for (i = 1; match != null; i++) { // You need to loop until you match every value
  // Full match is in match[0]
  // Your value is in match[1]
  console.log("Val"+i+": "+match[1])
  match = regex.exec(json);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with valid json you shouldn't need to use regex, and can deserialize it with the following:

```
var data = JSON.parse(json_string);
```

Comment: I do have the object, and serialize from there. The point of stringifying it is to flatten the object to extract the strings more easily (instead of walking though it)